# How to convert objects' fields to a list in Django?

Tags: python, django, list, tuples

I have a list of Competitors which are grouped into different groups (brackets) using Foreign Keys.

Models.py

```
class Group(models.Model):
  group_label = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.group_label

class Competitors(models.Model):
  flname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  Weight = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(50), MaxValueValidator(300)])
  rank = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  Group_FK = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='group_label')
  point = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

After assigning Competitors to their Group, how do I convert all of the flname in a Group into a tuple before using [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to create unique pair (matches) from it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `values_list` and specify that you want it as a flat list:

```
flnames = Competitors.objects.filter(Group_FK=Group.objects.get(pk=___).values_list('flname', flat=True)
```